# Print pandas dataframe with spyder in unicode format

Tags: python, printing, pandas, spyder

I am using Spyder 2.3.2 with Python 2.7.9

I have problems with printing data frames to console.

Consider this example

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame([u'\xa0'])
x.iloc[0,0]
```

This shows u'\xa0' in console which is fine.

But when i try to do this

```
x
```

or

```
print(x)
```

I get this error in spyder's Internal console

```
"return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True) 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 8:
invalid start byte"
```

My understanding is that this this happens because when printing the whole data frame spyder somehow tries to decode the characters from utf8 which in this case it can't do.

**Is there a way to somehow print everything in unicode instead of the automatic utf8 decoding?**

I would also appreciate if someone could explain what is exactly happening here to maybe help me solve the problem on higher level.

Comment: What does `pd.__version__`, `str(x)` and `unicode(x)` show?

Comment: pd.__version__ : 0.15.2
unicode(x) and str(x) won't raise an error and in this case they show 
'   0\n0  \xa0'. 
But this will get messy easily. I would somehow like to print the data frame neatly in columns just like any other dataframe but in case there is a string in some cell then it would be shown as unicode.

Comment: Actually I think I understand the problem now. When I do print(x) the Python just dumps the stuff out what I see in console when I do str(x). Then the console converts this stuff to neat rows and columns and now if some variable contains something what can't be handled with utf8 then I get an error.

Comment: That's interesting, since I am also using pandas version `0.15.2` but for me `str(x)` is `'   0\n0  \xc2\xa0'`. Notice the `'\xc2'`. My string decodes using `utf8` correctly.

Comment: Hmm this is very strange then.

Comment: Do you get the same result when running those commands in a non-spyder interactive console/terminal?

Comment: In IPython I get the correct '   0\n0  \xc2\xa0'. So is my spyder somehow buggy or what is going on?

Comment: I think this is a bug in Spyder.

Comment: Or, perhaps `Spyder` is setting `pd.options.display.encoding = 'latin1'`. This would cause `str(x)` to return `'   0\n0  \xa0'`. You might want to check the value of `pd.options.display.encoding`. If it return `'latin1'`, then set it back to `'utf-8'`.

Comment: latin1 didn't change the things.
But when I did  pd.options.display.encoding = 'utf8' everything works like a charm. str(x) shows the same with you. And print(x) works now as well.
It turned out that the default encoding was/is 'cp1252'.
Thank you so much for the help!! I have been fighting with this for a some time.
Maybe you should make your suggestion about display encoding to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: This issue will be fixed in Spyder 2.3.3. (Thanks, Carlos Cordoba.)

---

Pandas uses the codec specified by `pd.options.display.encoding` to encode unicode displayed on the console. (Type `print(pd.get_option.__doc__)` or `pd.get_option?` in IPython to see the full list of configurable options).

Per the comments, somehow `pd.options.display.encoding` has been set to
`'cp1252'`, but the console expects `'utf-8'`.

Hence, pandas converts `str(x)`
to `' 0\n0 \xa0'`, but the console decodes this string using `utf-8` which
results in a `UnicodeDecodeError`.

The solution is to reset the display encoding:

```
pd.options.display.encoding = 'utf-8'
```

since this is the encoding the console expects.

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) @unutbu thanks for the solution. I found that we were importing Pandas too early when creating a console, which lead it to incorrectly detect the console encoding. Could you update the answer to mention that this problem will be fixed in Spyder 2.3.3 and remove the mention `PYTHONSTARTUP` and all the rest of it?